# How to change the title color of UIToolbar buttons?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uiappearance

Is there any easy method to change the title color of UIToolBar button title like what we are using for UIBarButtonItem:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] 
    setTitleTextAttributes:
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor redColor], 
            UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Yes, they are same since both are `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: @Desdenova It's not changing for UIToolbarbutton

Comment: use UILable instead of doing all this stuff..

Comment: @Jeff it does. There is no such thing as `UIToolBarButton`. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: it does. If I use the exact same code in my app it works as expected. Prove: http://i.imgur.com/lWebP5g.png

Comment: @LOKESH.V I love how you say "use 9 lines of code" instead of doing all this stuff on 1 line

Answer (score 2):

`UITextAttributeTextColor` is **deprecated** in **iOS >= 7.0**.

Use `setTintColor:(UIColor *)` instead to change color of button's title.

Set default title color for `UIToolBar`:

```
[_myUIToolBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

or set title color of single `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
[_myUIBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
+(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItemWithTint:(UIColor*)color andTitle:(NSString*)itemTitle andTarget:(id)theTarget andSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    UISegmentedControl *button = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:itemTitle, nil]] autorelease];
    button.momentary = YES;
    button.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    button.tintColor = color;
    [button addTarget:theTarget action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    UIBarButtonItem *removeButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];

    return removeButton;
}
```

used this code or http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/03/31/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-uibarbuttonitem/ check this link

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Throughtout APP:

```
UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = TOOLBAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR
UIToolbar.appearance().tintColor = TOOLBAR_TITLE_COLOR
```

Also

```
 if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 15) {
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:TOOLBAR_TITLE_COLOR], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

//Best Way.. Try with setting the images for UIBarButtonItem..

```
UIButton *a1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[a1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 18.0f, 18.0f)];
[a1 addTarget:self action:@selector(BarButton_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[a1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UnSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[a1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
UIBarButtonItem *btn_Image = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:a1];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
[flexibleSpace setWidth:25.0];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,btn_Image,nil];
```

Answer (score -3):

here the sample code:

```
[UIToolbar appearance]
```

Adding after your text attribute:

[image]

Here a UIToolBar class reference:

[UIToolBar class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: not a single one of those methods listed in the autocompletion is available on [UIToolbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006927-CH3-SW4). You see those because appearance returns `id`. Don't get fooled by Xcode. Thanks to instancetype, with iOS7 SDK those bogus methods are gone.